# AngularJs- Route user to different dashboards from login page based upon his role

Tags: angularjs

I have just started learning AngularJs and I'm trying to make an app which will route the user to the appropriate dashboard based upon his role using AngularJs.

Can somebody help me?   Code is much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [angular ui router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/). And then after installing and setting it up, use its [Route to component](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem#route-to-component) feature. good luck.